# set offset/position of polygon to rotate

Tags: html5-canvas, kineticjs

I'm trying to perform a crop of a background image with different shapes.

The objective is to move/rotate around the polygons, crop the background with the shape of the polygon, somehow plot the cropped image over the polygon and save the cropped polygon as a new image.

So far I can drag and rotate(arrow keys) the polygons over the canvas.

First, I'm having problems rotating the polygons: I want them to rotate on its center.
And second, cropping the background with the polygon shape.

Here's a link to a jsbin: http://jsbin.com/efoqav/1/edit

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

**Here’s how to use your Kinetic polygon to clip a background image**

[image]

First, use the background image as a `fillPattern` in your Kinetic polygon.  Make the fill non-repeating and offset the pattern by the x/y position of the polygon:

```
var hexagon = new Kinetic.RegularPolygon({
  x: 50,
  y: 50,
  sides: 6,
  radius: 50,
  fillPatternImage: img,
  fillPatternRepeat: "no-repeat",
  fillPatternOffset: [-50,-50],
  stroke: 'black',
  strokeWidth: 3,
  draggable: true
});
```

Then when th user drags the polygon (or you move it with keystrokes), reposition the `fillPatternOffset` by the current position of the polygon.   Essentially, the fill inside the polygon will “follow” the dragging polygon.

```
hexagon.on('dragmove', function() {
  var position=this.getAbsolutePosition();
  var x=position.x;
  var y=position.y
  this.setFillPatternOffset(x,y);
  layer.draw();
});
```

To rotate your polygon around its center (centerX,centerY), do this trigonometry to each of your Kinetic Polygon Points and then reset the shape with yourKineticPolygon.setPoints.

```
// if the rotation angle is degrees, you must first convert it to radians:
var radianAngle = degreeAngle * Math.PI/180;

// modify each of your polygon points like this
var dx = centerX – pointX;
var dy = centerY – pointY;
var radius = Math.sqrt(  dx*dx + dy*dy);
var rotatedX = centerX + radius * Math.cos(radianAngle);
var rotatedY = centerY + radius * Math.cos(radianAngle);
```

And to save the stage to an image, you can use stage.toDataURL like this:

```
// hide the background since you're just interested in the clip
background.hide();

// this saves the stage (your clipped polygon) to an image url
stage.toDataURL({ 
    // just like an image object, you need an onload-ish callback
    callback: function(dataUrl){
        // testing -- put the image in an html img 
        var imgElement=document.getElementById("saved");
        imgElement.src=dataUrl;
        // reshow the background
        background.show();
    }
});
```

Here’s code and a Fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/eQYB8/

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://d3lp1msu2r81bx.cloudfront.net/kjs/js/lib/kinetic-v4.5.1.min.js"></script>

<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory;  padding:20px;}
    img{border:1px solid red;}
</style>

<script>
$(function(){

    // this just generates a sample image
    var canvas=document.createElement("canvas");
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
    var count=0;
    canvas.width=300;
    canvas.height=300;
    for(var x=0;x<10;x++){
        for(var y=0;y<10;y++){
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.arc(x*30+15,y*30+15,15,0,Math.PI*2,false);
            ctx.fillText(count++,x*30+11,y*30+18);
            ctx.stroke();
        }
    }
    var img=new Image();
    img.onload=function(){
        draw();
    }
    img.src=canvas.toDataURL();


    function draw(){

            var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
              container: 'container',
              width: 300,
              height: 300
            });
            var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
            stage.add(layer);

            var background = new Kinetic.Image({
              x: 0,
              y: 0,
              image: img,
              width: 300,
              height: 300,
              opacity:.25
            });
            layer.add(background);

            var hexagon = new Kinetic.RegularPolygon({
              x: 50,
              y: 50,
              sides: 6,
              radius: 50,
              fillPatternImage: img,
              fillPatternRepeat: "no-repeat",
              fillPatternOffset: [-50,-50],
              stroke: 'black',
              strokeWidth: 3,
              draggable: true
            });
            layer.add(hexagon);
            layer.draw();


            hexagon.on('dragmove', function() {
              var position=this.getAbsolutePosition();
              var x=position.x;
              var y=position.y
              this.setFillPatternOffset(x,y);
              layer.draw();
            });

            $("#save").click(function(){
                background.hide();
                stage.toDataURL({ 
                    callback: function(dataUrl){
                        var imgElement=document.getElementById("saved");
                        imgElement.src=dataUrl;
                        background.show();
                    }
                });
            });

    }

}); // end $(function(){});
</script>

</head>

<body>
    <button id="save">Save</button><br><br>
    <p>Drag the Polygon to your desired clip</p><br>
    <div id="container"></div><br>
    <p>Saved results without background</p>
    <img id="saved" width=300 height=300/>
</body>
</html>
```